# Upgraded SSIS package fails to run, "must install Standard Edition of Integration Services"

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I was forced to upgrade my SSIS packages using VS2015 + SSDT, however I'm unable to get the compiled dtsx files to run now through command line using `130\DTS\Binn\DTExec.exe`

**Full error:**

```
 Source: Process file data flow SSIS.Pipeline
 Description: To run a SSIS package outside of SQL Server Data Tools you must install Standard Edition of Integration Services or higher.
```

I've reinstalled MSSQL2014 w/ integration services and I see `SQL Server Integration Services 12` is running.

Comment: Are you using DTexec.exe to run the SSIS package from the command line? If so, DTExec.exe gets installed when you pick the "Integration Services" option off the CD. Make sure that it's installed in the directory indicated in the command line.

Comment: @Tarzan I am, it is running however gives me an error when running the package. The exe is there.

Comment: Is there a version mismatch between the SSIS package and DTExec.exe?

Comment: The "130" part of your 130\DTS\Binn\DTExec.exe path indicates that you may be calling the MSSQL2016 version rather than 2014.

Comment: @Tarzan thanks I'll see if the integration portion was not installed with 2016

Comment: Visual Studio 2015 makes SSIS packages that are compatible with SQL Server 2016.  To make packages for SQL Server 2014, you should be using Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: @Tarzan please post an answer, this resolved the issue!

Comment: @TabAlleman Correction - "to make packages for SQL Server 2014, you should be using Visual Studio 2013"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DTExec.exe gets installed when you pick the "Integration Services" option off the setup CD. Make sure that it's installed in the directory indicated in the command line. You also need to make sure that the versions match between the SSIS package and  DTEXec.exe. "..\120\DTS\Binn\DTExec.exe" is used for MSSQL2014.

Answer (score 0):

I received this error from double-clicking a DTSX file which opened the Execute Package Utility from C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140. I couldn't get it to work until I:

1. Saved off the command line from the "Command-line" tab of the utility
2. Navigated to C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\Binn
3. Called dtexec.exe with the command line

I think the Execute Package Utility was somehow looking for SQL Server 17 while I only had SQL 16 installed. DTExec.exe was able to find SQL 16 ok.